# Error Exception PHP 8.1.2 9.5.1 Array to string conversion Laravel Ecommerce

Tags: laravel

I'm in dire need of your assistance. I'm following a Laravel 8 Ecommerce tutorial and Im at the checkout stage.

After following all the steps and reconfirming the code a couple of times I get the error subject every time while the tutorial proceeds to success and its driving me nuts!! Pls someone help me understand where I'm going wrong. Thank you. Below is the code. All solutions will be appreciated.

Livewire relationship models
Order Model:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "orders";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }

    public function shipping()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Shipping::class);
    }

    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Transaction::class);
    }
}
```

OrderItem

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "order_items";

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Shipping Model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shipping extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "shippings";

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Transaction Model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "transactions";

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Checkout Component

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Cart;
use App\Models\Order;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Shipping;
use App\Models\OrderItem;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckoutComponent extends Component

{
    public $ship_to_different;

    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $mobile;
    public $email;
    public $line1;
    public $line2;
    public $city;
    public $address;
    public $country;
    public $zipcode;

    public $s_firstname;
    public $s_lastname;
    public $s_mobile;
    public $s_email;
    public $s_line1;
    public $s_line2;
    public $s_city;
    public $s_address;
    public $s_country;
    public $s_zipcode;

    public $paymentmode;
    public $thankyou;

    public function updated($fields)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($fields, [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'mobile' => 'required|numeric',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'line1' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'zipcode' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($this->ship_to_different) {
            $this->validateOnly($fields, [
                's_firstname' => 'required',
                's_lastname' => 'required',
                's_mobile' => 'required|numeric',
                's_email' => 'required|email',
                's_line1' => 'required',
                's_city' => 'required',
                's_address' => 'required',
                's_country' => 'required',
                's_zipcode' => 'required',

            ]);
        }
    }
    
    public function placeOrder()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'mobile' => 'required|numeric',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'line1' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'zipcode' => 'required'
        ]);

        $order = new Order();
        $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $order->subtotal = session()->get('checkout', ['subtotal']);
        $order->discount = session()->get('checkout', ['discount']);
        $order->tax = session()->get('checkout', ['tax']);
        $order->total = session()->get('checkout', ['total']);
        $order->firstname = $this->firstname;
        $order->lastname = $this->lastname;
        $order->mobile = $this->mobile;
        $order->email = $this->email;
        $order->line1 = $this->line1;
        $order->line2 = $this->line2;
        $order->city = $this->city;
        $order->address = $this->address;
        $order->country = $this->country;
        $order->zipcode = $this->zipcode;
        $order->status = 'ordered';
        $order->is_shipping_different = $this->ship_to_different ? 1 : 0;
        $order->save();

        

        foreach ((Cart::instance('cart'))->content() as $item) {
            $orderItem = new OrderItem();
            $orderItem->product_id = $item->id;
            $orderItem->order_id = $order->id;
            $orderItem->price = $item->price;
            $orderItem->quantity = $item->qty;
            $orderItem->save();
        }

        if ($this->ship_to_different) {
            $this->validate([
                's_firstname' => 'required',
                's_lastname' => 'required',
                's_mobile' => 'required|numeric',
                's_email' => 'required|email',
                's_line1' => 'required',
                's_city' => 'required',
                's_address' => 'required',
                's_country' => 'required',
                's_zipcode' => 'required'
            ]);

            $shipping = new Shipping();
            $shipping->order_id = $order->id;
            $shipping->firstname = $this->s_firstname;
            $shipping->lastname = $this->s_lastname;
            $shipping->mobile = $this->s_mobile;
            $shipping->email = $this->email;
            $shipping->line1 = $this->s_line1;
            $shipping->line2 = $this->s_line2;
            $shipping->city = $this->s_city;
            $shipping->address = $this->s_address;
            $shipping->country = $this->s_country;
            $shipping->zipcode = $this->s_zipcode;
            $shipping->save();
        }

        if ($this->paymentmode == 'cod') {
            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $transaction->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $transaction->order_id = $order->id;
            $transaction->mode = 'cod';
            $transaction->status = 'pending';
            $transaction->save();
        }

        $this->thankyou = 1;
        Cart::instance('cart')->destroy();
        session()->forget('checkout');
    }

    public function verifyForCheckout()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        } else if ($this->thankyou) {
            return redirect()->route('thankyou');
        } else if (!session()->get('checkout')) {
            return redirect()->route('product.cart');
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->verifyForCheckout();
        return view('livewire.checkout-component')->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

Comment: What line, specifically, is throwing that error? (And don't give us the line number, show the actual code that's triggering that. Stackoverflow doesn't have line numbers)

Comment: foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
        }
        return $result;
    }

Comment: That line of code is not the question that you posted...

Comment: Im new to Laravel pls see this stack trace of the error. https://flareapp.io/share/Lm8LlVRm#F57

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/Lm8LlVRm#F56: You can see this error is triggered when `$order->save()` is called. If I had to guess, it would be these lines: `$order->subtotal = session()->get('checkout', ['subtotal']);` (and the following). The 2nd argument of `get()` is the fallback, not the access. Did you maybe mean `session()->get('checkout')['subtotal']`? Might be better to define `$checkout = session()->get('checkout')`, then set them via `$order->subtotal = $checkout['subtotal']`, etc.

Comment: as you can see from the error log, in your file `\app\Http\Livewire\CheckoutComponent.php
:106` you are setting one of the fields value an array when in your database it's a string.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you. I think that is what was missing. The logic behind it.. appreciated.

Comment: I went with the first solution `session()->get('checkout')['subtotal']`  and it worked like a charm. We have liftoff!

Comment: No worries! Remember to use debugging tools like `dd()` to help you self-debug this. If you had done `dd(session()->get('checkout', ['subtotal']))` you would have seen the array `['subtotal' => ..., 'discount' => ..., 'tax' => ..., 'total' => ...]`, and may have been able to debug from there. Also, understanding the arguments to `session()->get()`; the first argument `'checkout'` is the Key to look for, the 2nd `['subtotal']` is the fallback. So if `session()->get('checkout')` was `null`, you'd have `['subtotal']` as your value. That also is invalid, but you get the idea  Glad it's working!

Comment: @TimLewis can you have your comment your suggestion as an "answer" to get it marked as the one ?

Comment: @BabacarCisséDia I could convert to an answer, but I likely won't as this is a simple syntax error/not reproducible. `session()->get('checkout', ['subtotal'])`, while syntactically valid, is still a syntax error when trying to get the value from `subtotal` array index. `session()->get('checkout')['subtotal']` is correct. I have already voted to close as a syntax error, there is no need to post an answer. In fact, this question should probably just be deleted.